# Find out X server window manager from X client

Tags: ssh, xorg, x11-forwarding, xforwarding

I login on a remote machine with `ssh -X`. My local machine runs a non-reparenting WM.

The remote machine needs to know what WM the machine running the X server uses, in order to set or unset an environment variable for java.

In other words, I need to do something like this in `~/.bashrc` of the remote machine:

```
if [ $DESKTOP_SESSION == xmonad ] ; then
    export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1
fi
```

The problem is that `DESKTOP_SESSION` does not say anything there. I need something that tells the remote machine in which environment the windows are going to be displayed in.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

(Nothing sets or uses $DESKTOP_VERSION. Did you mean $DESKTOP_SESSION? That's the one where display managers store the name of the xsession file they chose.)

To query the current window manager's name, use `wmctrl -m`. Don't forget proper quoting as the name may have spaces.

```
wm=$(wmctrl -m | sed -n 's/^Name: //p')
if [ "$wm" = xmonad ]; then
    ...
fi
```

*(Bash's `[[` doesn't need quoting on LHS, but POSIX `[` does.)*

The mechanism works by first querying the `_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK` property of the X11 root window, then querying properties of the returned window ID.

```
$ xprop -root _NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK
_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK(WINDOW): window id # 0x600006

$ xprop -id 0x600006 _NET_WM_NAME
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "GNOME Shell"
```

Comment: Right, I mean DESKTOP_SESSION, thanks. I'd rather not add a dependency to `wmctrl`. Using `xprop` to examine the WM seems interesting, I don't have `_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK` but maybe there's something to dig there.